# Avoid overshoot or undershoot in graph

Tags: c++, cairo, sampling, resampling

In current application, we have 1000 data points which use to plot graph using Cairo library. It's generating graph file but it has overshoot in graph. I need to remove this overshoot or undershoot from the graph. I heard that people use sampling theorem to remove undershoot or overshoot.
The application is written in C++. Let me know if I need to provide more info.
I tried to use following code to remove this overshoot(I could not understand below code in better way)

```
int samplesize = 4;
double prevSample = 0;
double prevslope = 0;
int thePoint = 0;

for (unsigned int i = samplesize, j = startXIndex; i < endXIndex; i++, j++) {
    double sample = 0;

    for (unsigned int k = j; k <= i; k++) {
        sample += (xvals[k]*xvals[k]);
    }

    sample /= (i-j);
    sample = sqrt(sample);

    double slope = atan(prevSample-sample);

    if (((prevslope <= 0 && slope > 0) || (prevslope >= 0 && slope < 0))) {
        thePoint = j;
    }

    prevslope = slope;
    prevSample = sample;
}

lowX = xvals[thePoint];
```

Can anyone provide me input to fix this issue.[image]

Comment: Your overshoot (I guess you mean the purple lines) is caused by lack of high frequencies. To get them back, increase your sampling frequency. It has to be at least twice the highest signal frequency. If you don't have enough samples for that, interpolate before sampling. If your signal has unlimited high frequencies, you'll always have some overshoot.